# javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.TransactionException: Already have an associated managed connection

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I am using JPA + Hibernate in my application. I try to insert 10000 data in mysql DB. But i got this error. How to solve ?

javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.TransactionException: Already have an associated managed connection

Caused by: org.hibernate.TransactionException: Already have an associated managed connection

```
    //For loop call 10000 times in getMdmId() method and pass MdmId object each time.


    //@PersistenceContext
    @PersistenceContext(type = PersistenceContextType.TRANSACTION)
    private static EntityManager em = getEntityManager();
    public static String getMdmId(MdmId mdm) {

        String mdmId = "";
        EntityTransaction tr = em.getTransaction();

        try {
            if (!tr.isActive())
                tr.begin();
                em.persist(mdm);
                mdmId = Long.toString(mdm.getId());
            //  tr.commit();
            if (tr.isActive()) tr.commit();
            else em.flush();

        } catch (Exception error) {
            logger.error(error.getMessage());
            if (tr.isActive()) tr.rollback();
            error.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("----"+mdmId);
        return mdmId;
    }

    private  static EntityManager getEntityManager() {
        return Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("sql-connection").createEntityManager();
    }
```

Comment: If you are creating your own EntityManager using Persistence factory, why are you annotating the field for container injection?

Comment: before this error i got another error . i search stack overflow then find this anotation answer

Comment: The PersistenceContext annotation only make sense if you are using a container (javaee ou CDI), which it does not appear to be true. Could you please clarify who calls the method, if it is a managed bean (CDI or Spring) or standalone and what command throws the error?